# How do I draw a line on top of a cv2 generated image?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to draw a line on top of a black image.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
//black image
img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)

img = cv2.line(img, (130, 130),  (202, 202), (0,0,255), 2)
cv2.imshow('resize', img)
```

The black image works as expected while the line part seems to fail to render? What am I missing?

Comment: your code is fine, and has everything you need to draw a line on a black image

Comment: try to install opencv again

Comment: your code should be ok, but can you try to draw in color   
 (255,255,255). Just in the case that your used code differs from your posted code and you somewhere converted to single-channel image or sth... And please use a waitKey(0) if you didnt yet, zo actually render the image to the window.

Answer (score 1):

Run this script to uninstall `opencv` and install it again

```
from pip._internal import main
main(["uninstall", "opencv-python"])
main(["install", "opencv-python"])

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
# black image
img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)

img = cv2.line(img, (130, 130),  (202, 202), (0,0,255), 2)
cv2.imshow("resize", img)
```

**Good luck**

Answer (score 0):

It renders fine for me. Can you try this code and see if it shows up?

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
# black image
img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)

img = cv2.line(img, (130, 130),  (202, 202), (0,0,255), 2)
cv2.imshow('resize', img)
cv2.waitKey(0);
```